# node-pre-gyp err while trying to npm install

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm

While trying to install [sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) I'm getting an error running with:

- npm  v6.4.1
- node v8.11.4
- Windows 10

I tried to clean cache, reinstall nodejs/npm and some random things I found in other questions here(like setting msvs version, setting python config var etc.)

Error log:

```
kawthar@Romana MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Nodev/Artesã (JS)
$ npm install sqlite --save    

> sqlite3@4.0.2 install C:\Users\kawthar\Desktop\Nodev\Artesã (JS)\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

'node-pre-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm WARN qi-bot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN qi-bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kawthar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-30T22_28_34_617Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I had to install it globally on windows: `npm install -g node-pre-gyp`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command and try again:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: Now I get 
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain 
Any suggestions?